# Updating ordinal numbers for child records in MySQL table

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

**MySQL database**

Each row from `article` has 0 to 10 rows in `price`,
but `ordNum` is empty as I added it after few years.

Is there an one-liner to set `ordNum` so that each article gets values from `1` to `n` for its prices?
For example, article that has 3 prices should have their `ordNum` set to `1`, `2` and `3`.

The order of the prices is not important, but it would be an added value if it could be taken into account.

**Articles:**

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
    `id`   INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` TEXT    NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

**Prices:**

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
    `id`          INT(11)     NOT NULL,
    `amount`      VARCHAR(24) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `article_id`  INT(11)     NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `currency_id` INT(11)     NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ordNum`      INT(11)     NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

**NOTE:** This question is **not** duplicate of [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) as it takes two different tables in account comparing to single table in [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY article_id ORDER BY amount) AS ordNum
  FROM price
)
UPDATE price JOIN cte USING (id)
SET price.ordNum = cte.ordNum;
```

This requires MySQL 8.0 for the CTE and window function.

`ORDER BY` is just an example; you can choose another order if you want.

Comment: I know Oracle has partition by clause and rownum pseudocolumn but I didn't even dream of MySQL having any of it.  Your query did the job the way I wanted. Tnx!

Comment: @horvoje You might like to bookmark modern-sql.com, which compares lots of brands of SQL databases for compliance. For example: https://modern-sql.com/feature/with and https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/over_partition_by